# clear UIView drawing from UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

okay, about to freak out...

making a drawing app:
Main view (buttons, ads, etc)
then a container view taking up a portion of the screen (with a custom drawing class)
When the user clicks a button in the Main view it triggers an event in the container view (probably a better way to do this but I can't find it)

As the user presses somewhere inside the container it records the point, adds a line and then updates the draw:rect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [incImage drawInRect:rect];
    [path stroke];
}
```

(as the user draws, the UIImage ('incImage') gets added onto and as it does, it is painted onto the view)

Drawing code:

```
- (void)drawBitmap
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:_brushR green:_brushG blue:_brushB alpha:_brushO] setStroke];
    [incImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [path stroke];
    incImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

However I can't clear the view!
I've tried splitting the draw:Rect method into 2 sections (if clear is true and if it is not) and doing this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
rectpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0,0,incImage.size.width,incImage.size.height)];
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
[rectpath fill];
[incImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
incImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
_clear=true;
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

then changing draw:Rect to:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (clear) {
        [incImage drawInRect:rect];
        [rectpath fill];
    }
    else {
        [incImage drawInRect:rect];
        [path stroke];
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work (I've also tried creating a CGRect and then filling it with white and making that the image and tried to draw that image to the view but with no luck).  I have also checked and the problem is not the Main view communicating and calling methods from the container view, there's something wrong with the way I'm trying to go about this or my draw method.

ANY help would be greatly appreciated, my Mac's life may depend on it :)

Comment: Do you clear the rect anywhere? I don't see it, but not sure we're seeing all the code. If not, add this to your drawRect: CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);

Comment: I did try doing this in my draw:rect method:
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (!_clr) {
        [incImage drawInRect:rect];
        [path stroke];
    }

    if (_clr) {
        CGContextClearRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
        incImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        [incImage drawInRect:rect];
    }
}

still nothing

Answer (score 1):

Create function like this:

```
-(void) clearDrawing {
    incImage = nil;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

It will delete incImage, so it will no longer be displayed in `-(void) drawRect`. And if you want to show something again you can call `-(void)drawBitmap` which will execute this: `incImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();` and the incImage will be recreated again with some drawing.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you [edit]ed it to explain why it works.

Answer (score 0):

When `-drawRect:` is called, the view will already have been erased. It sounds like you're recording the points by adding them to `path`. When you want to "clear" the view, you need to update the object that's storing the data that's being rendered -- in your case, that probably means resetting `path` either by calling `-removeAllPoints` or by simply throwing away the old path and starting fresh with a new one.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but that doesn't help the problem, what I should of stated is that as the user draws, the locations of the points are recorded in 'path' and then they are drawn, as soon as the user lifts their finger off the screen 'path' has all it's points removed (so when the user draws again, it's only drawing new lines instead of everything-or at least that's how I understand it) so I don't see how that would work.

Comment: Yes, a detailed description of the problem always helps. It sounds like you're creating a new path whenever a new touch begins, adding points to the path as the touch moves, and destroying the path when the touch ends? In any case, look carefully at what happens to the path object as the touch progresses and after it ends. How does the path get stored? (If it doesn't get stored, that's part of the problem.) You might want to read up on the [Model View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html) paradigm as it's used in iOS.